# When closing a notepad process im getting exception why is that?

Tags: c#

This is the code:

```
private void processNotePad_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                View_Log_File.Enabled = true;
            });
        }
```

In Form1 i have a menu i click on it and a new Form is opened there i have a button click wich open a log files(txt file) using notepad.exe 
If i first close the notepad then close the menu form it's all ok.
But if i first close the menu form and after it trying to close the notepad im getting an exception:

The exception error is: Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created

```
System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created.
  Source=System.Windows.Forms
  StackTrace:
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.MarshaledInvoke(Control caller, Delegate method, Object[] args, Boolean synchronous)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invoke(Delegate method, Object[] args)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invoke(Delegate method)
       at mws.SettingsMenu.processNotePad_Exited(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\C-Sharp\Download File\Downloading-File-Project-Version-012\Downloading File\SettingsMenu.cs:line 148
       at System.Diagnostics.Process.OnExited()
       at System.Diagnostics.Process.RaiseOnExited()
       at System.Diagnostics.Process.CompletionCallback(Object context, Boolean wasSignaled)
       at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitOrTimerCallback.WaitOrTimerCallback_Context(Object state, Boolean timedOut)
       at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitOrTimerCallback.WaitOrTimerCallback_Context_f(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitOrTimerCallback.PerformWaitOrTimerCallback(Object state, Boolean timedOut)
  InnerException:
```

How should i take care in this situation ? If the user first close the menu form and then the notepad it will throw this exception.

Comment: How about closing the NotePad window in the Windows Forms FormClosing EventHandler

Comment: remove `processNotePad_Exited` from the delegate/event it is subscribed to when form closes.

Comment: You mean if the user is trying to close first the menu form so it will close first the notepad ? So doing it in the menu form FormClosing event will close first the notepad.

Comment: Mark Hall i did what you wrote and it's working just fine.

Comment: Glad to help, I will add as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are having an error if the Menu form is closed before the NotePad window, I would suggest that you use the Menu Forms [FormClosing EventHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to close the NotePad Window before the Menu Form closes.

From above link:

> The FormClosing event occurs as the form is being closed. When a form is closed, it is disposed, releasing all resources associated with the form. If you cancel this event, the form remains opened. To cancel the closure of a form, set the Cancel property of the FormClosingEventArgs passed to your event handler to true.